# get data from jframe into previous jframe in java?

Tags: java

From jframe1 I have a table containing data from sql. I press the search button on jframe1 and it will appear jframe2 for me to enter the information to search. When I click the OK button on jframe2, the jframe1 table will change to only the data stream to search. I have to do. My problem is transferring data from jframe2 to jframe1

Comment: show your attempt code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some class, or a new one if you want to make one, set your current instance of `jframe1` so you can access it when ever.  Where ever `jframe1` is stored, pass an instance of that class to `jframe2` when initializing it.

From here you could get the `jframe1` from `jframe2`, and I would suggest creating a method in jframe1 to set/send this "data" to it when `jframe2` is read to do so.

---

If you are doing this with more than 1 Jframe I would suggest doing something similar to what I said above, but for any frame which can have data sent to it, implement an interface you could create to make your code more neat and structured.  Then make a field in some class all frames have access to and this field could be a List or array of JFrames. Then if you want to send this "data" to all these frames, loop through the frames and check if the frame implements your interface, or something like this:

```
for(JFrame frame : objectWhereFramesAre.getFrames()){
    if(frame instanceof YourInterface){
        frame.setData(/*send data here*/);
    }
}
```